# Совершенный вид?

Tags: глаголы

If someone asks me

> Почему ты не сделал домашние задание?

How do I Have to answer?

> Мы с другом *сходили* с собакой

или

> Мы с другом *ходили* с собакой

Answer (score 3):

Почему ты не **сделал** домашнее задание? means "Why haven't you done the homework?", so the person who asked it wants to know if you have finished the homework, is there is a result of doing the homework.

Почему ты не **делал** домашнее задание? means "Why haven't you been doing the homework", so the person who asked it wants to know why haven't you started to do the homework, he (she) is interested in the action of doing the homework, not in the result.

So, the answer to the first question would be: "Я не сделал домашнее задание, потому что оно очень трудное" or "Я не сделал домашнее задание, потому что заболел".

In the second example of yours, there are two verbs of motion. **"Ходить"** is always imperfective and means a two-way motion on foot. If you use this verb, you have to name the exact direction: "Мы с другом ходили с собакой **в лес**", for example. It means that you went to the forest and then returned. The verb "ходить" can also denote the absense of direction or a multi-directional movement, so it could also be: "Мы с другом ходили с собакой **по лесу**".

**"Сходить"** is a perfective verb of motion means a quick two-way motion of foot. "Мы с другом сходили с собакой в лес" means you went to the forest quickly an then returned.

Answer (score 3):

A better translation would be

> мы с другом гуляли с собакой

which is similar to

> Мы с другом ходили с собакой

except that it sounds more natural when referring to a walk with a dog.

I think that the other option may also work in some contexts

> Мы с другом сходили с собакой

It's not as good as the other option, because `ходили` reflects the prolonged duration of the activity, which caused you to not work on your homework.

Btw, any parent will attest that it's not unusual excuse for skipping the home work :)